# Silly question about square roots in a linear algebra problem.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I was reading a linear algebra problem about spectral descomposition or a square simetrical matrix and there is a part where from $-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$ then the book gets $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$ but I already try it and I really dont see it so far I got that $-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{3}}$ just by using some basic arithmetic , is the book wrong or which is the step I dont see ? I really need help seeing this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}= \frac{2}{2\sqrt{2}}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Multiply by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ to get $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{3}}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$
-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}
$$